# Web client polls backend to check it's up

Tags: javascript, http, server, backend

A web client should only expose some features when a backend API is up and running. Therefor, I'm looking for a clean way to monitor the availability of this backend.

As a quick fix, I made a timer-based function that performs a basic GET on the API root. It's not very clean, generates lots of traffic and pollutes the javascript console with errors (in case of server down).

How should one deal with such situation?

Comment: You are using serverside Javascript?

Comment: This question seems to be a better fit for the [Software Enginnering StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) website. However, off the top of my head: You could use an AJAx interceptor to turn off the services if the API does not respond as expected. You could also run a manual check when the application starts to ensure the services are up.

Comment: @ChiragRavindra when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat did not know about that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger something in the lines of this when you need it:

```
function checkServerStatus()
{
    setServerStatus("unknown");
    var img = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
    img.onload = function()
    {
        setServerStatus("online");
    };
    img.onerror = function()
    {
        setServerStatus("offline");
    };
    img.src = "http://myserver.com/ping.gif";
}
```

Make `ping.gif` small (1 pixel) to make it as fast as possible.
Ofc you can do it more smoothly by accessing the API that returns true and keeps a really small response time, but that requires you to do some coding in back-end this simply needs you to place a 1-pixel gif image in a correct directory on a server. You can use any picture already present on the server, but expect more traffic and time as image grows larger.

Now put this in some function that calls it with delay, or simply call this when you need to check status, it's up to you.

If you need a server to send to your app a notification when it's down then you need to implement this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Ideally, you would have high-reliability server that has fast response rate and is really reliable to be pinging the desired server in some interval to determine whether it up then use the push to get that information to your app. This way that 3rd server would only send you a push if a status of your app server has changed. Ideally, this server's request has a high priority on your app server queue and servers are well connected and close to each other but not on the same network in case that fails.

**Recommendation:**

**First approach** should do you good since it's simple to implement and requires the least amount of knowledge.

**Consider second if:**
You need a really small interval of checking making your application slower and network traffic higher
You have multiple applications that need the same - making load heavier on both each application, network AND the server. The second approach lets you use single ping to determine truth for all apps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to limit number of request, simple solution can be use of **server-sent events**. This protocol used on top of HTTP allow server to push multiple updates in response of the same client request.

Client side code (javascript) :

```
var evtSource = new EventSource("backend.php");
evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('status:' + e.data);
}

evtSource.onerror = function(e) {
    // add some retry then display error to the user
}
```

Backend code (PHP, also supported by other languages)

```
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");
while (1) {
    // Each 30s, send OK status
    echo "OK\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(30);
}
```

In both case it will limit number of request (only 1 per "session") but you will have 1 socket per client opened, which can be also to heavy for your server.

If you really want to lower the workload, you should delegate it to external monitoring platform which can expose API to publish backend status.
Maybe it already exists if your backend is hosted on cloud platform.